# Failing to download SRTM data from USGS

Tags: dem, srtm, usgs

I was used to download SRTM/DEM data from the following link: https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/

But I'm not being able to download anymore, I don't know the exact causes of that, it was really practical since the images were all segmented by regions.

Does anyone have any idea why the link is down? Is there anywhere else where data can be acquired easily just clicking on links and downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment SRTM data are downloadable through these sites:

**SRTM 90**

https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

**SRTM 30**

https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/

Let's hope the USGS site recovers soon.